# Asset Write off calculation Automation

Tags: excel, excel-formula

How do I show all the write-off value in the year of the write-off?

I have the below model were in:
The formula in cell(O,29) is =

-SUM(OFFSET(O14,,,1,-MIN($G$20,P$3))/$G$20)+IF(O23=1,0,SUM(OFFSET(O14,,,1,-MIN($G$20,P$3))/$G$20)).

This gives me the flag year depreciation but I wanted all the remaining depreciation so it should be $120.

[image]

Comment: Could you explain why the depreciation in `O29` should be `$120`?

Comment: Why is there no depreciation recorded for the 1st 3 years?  Without that I think a formula would be difficult, since row 31 shows that depreciation isn't always apportioned equally to each year of the useful life...

Comment: @P.b thank you for the reply. I am depreciating $300 from FY 25 upto next 4 year. Then in row 23, I have a flag that says the computer would be written off in FY 27.. So there is 2 years (for FY 27 and FY 28) remaining for the $300 to be depreciated which is $120 ($60 and 60).  So, I want to show all the $120 in cell (O,27). This is the year I assuming all the remaining asset is written off.
Please let me know if this helps.

Comment: -Spectral Instance. I am just showing the write-off instead of depreciation. The depreciation is calculated in the part of the formula "-SUM(OFFSET(O14,,,1,-MIN($G$20,P$3))/$G$20)".
Please let me know if this helps.

Comment: You want the formula to calculate the remaining depreciation, which is the cost less the depreciation charged for the first 3 years - your model does not show this 180 anywhere... (and row 31 shows that it would not be wise to try to calculate it based on the number of prior years multiplied by an annual depreciation charge) e.g. prior years' depreciation _is_ shown for furniture

Answer (score 0):

How about this in `O29`:

```
=LET(period,     5,
     value,      I14:W14,
     flag,       I23:W23,
     startvalue, FILTER(value,value<>""),
     start,      FILTER(COLUMN(value),value<>""),
     writtenoff, startvalue/period*(COLUMN()-start),
IF(O23="",
   "",
   startvalue-writtenoff))
```

If you would drag this down/left/right, this would also take into account the 2 values for the convertor belts, for instance.